# Форматирование вывода данных из БД. Обработка данных

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу скрипт для обработки данных. Есть список словарей из БД, названия колонок в БД соответствуют ключам словаря:

```
list = [{'name': 'CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX', 'description': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 'softwarecomponent': 'cm-locale-russian_russian_federation', 'version': '11.5.1.3000-1'},
    {'name': 'CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX', 'description': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 'softwarecomponent': 'po-locale-russian_russian_federation', 'version': 'k3-12.1.1.1000-1'},
    {'name': 'CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX', 'description': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 'softwarecomponent': 'cm-locale-english_united_states', 'version': '11.0.0.0(1)'},
    {'name': 'CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX', 'description': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 'softwarecomponent': 'master', 'version': '11.5.1.16900(16)'},
    {'name': 'CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX', 'description': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 'softwarecomponent': 'cm-ver', 'version': '11.5.1.16900(16)'}]
```

Пытаюсь получить вывод в виде:

```
name             description     softwarecomponent                    version
CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX cm-locale-russian_russian_federation 11.5.1.3000-1
CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX po-locale-russian_russian_federation k3-12.1.1.1000-1
CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX cm-locale-english_united_states      11.0.0.0(1)
CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX master                               11.5.1.16900(16)
CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX cm-ver                               11.5.1.16900(16)`
```

Я сформировал словарь из названия колонок и максимальной длины строки-значения в данной колонке:

```
string_size = {}

for item in list:
    headlines = [key for key, val in item.items()]

    for i in headlines:
        if i not in string_size:
            string_size[i] = len(item[i])
        else:
            if string_size[i] < len(item[i]):
                string_size[i] = len(item[i])
```

Подскажите, как сформировать строку-заголовок и вывести данные с определенным количеством пробелов исходя и того что количество столбцов может быть произвольным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas

data = [{'name': 'CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX', 'description': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 'softwarecomponent': 'cm-locale-russian_russian_federation', 'version': '11.5.1.3000-1'},
    {'name': 'CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX', 'description': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 'softwarecomponent': 'po-locale-russian_russian_federation', 'version': 'k3-12.1.1.1000-1'},
    {'name': 'CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX', 'description': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 'softwarecomponent': 'cm-locale-english_united_states', 'version': '11.0.0.0(1)'},
    {'name': 'CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX', 'description': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 'softwarecomponent': 'master', 'version': '11.5.1.16900(16)'},
    {'name': 'CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX', 'description': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 'softwarecomponent': 'cm-ver', 'version': '11.5.1.16900(16)'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

```
In [44]: print(df)
       description              name                     softwarecomponent           version
0  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX  cm-locale-russian_russian_federation     11.5.1.3000-1
1  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX  po-locale-russian_russian_federation  k3-12.1.1.1000-1
2  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX       cm-locale-english_united_states       11.0.0.0(1)
3  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX                                master  11.5.1.16900(16)
4  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX                                cm-ver  11.5.1.16900(16)
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как его заставить показывать все колонки:
Получаю вывод                 name  ...           version
                  0   CM_s-xxx-p-xxxXX  ...     11.5.1.3000-1

Comment: @Luarvick, у вас задача вывести на экран или сохранить в файл?

Comment: Вывод будет идти в виджет Text, есть небольшой GUI написаный на tkinter, но по своей сути тоже самое что и print().

Comment: решил проблему: pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)